# MIT OCW Python Course in Highest Quality

Tags: python

I am currently learning Python from MIT OCW courses ? Anyone who have used it might know this...
where can I get the highest quality video to download from offline usage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A question was posted earlier asking for a link to Handouts. It was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671443/handouts-for-6-00-from-mit-ocw)